# vue component method change data by variable

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I want to change array data,change it in vue methods.

https://codepen.io/deded007/project/editor/AQyykN

My question is how to change the data by using a variable like this

```
created() {
  var a=this.thisisarray;
  this.thisisarray=[10];
  console.log('a expected '+this.thisisarray+',but '+ a);
}
```

It's ok to use `this.thisisarray` directly.But it's not working to change variable `a`.My variable is still looking at the old reference.I always get `a expected 10,but 9999`
I want to create a global method and pass my variable `a` to change it.

```
Vue.component('page-head', {
  template: '#page-head',
  data() {
    return {
      thisisarray:['a','b']
    };
  },
  created() {

      var a=this.thisisarray;
      this.thisisarray=[10];
      console.log('a expected '+this.thisisarray+',but '+ a);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

numbers are copied.  `t` is independent of `tom` once copied.

this is not a vue thing, this is how javascript works.  You are getting confused with reference types.  Where if you had

```
{
   tom: { value: 9999 }
}
```

and then did

```
var t = this.tom;
this.tom.value = 10
console.log('t expected '+this.tom.value +',but '+ t.value);
```

you'd get what you were expecting

**Now you've altered your code:**

You are now assigning a new reference to your data, but your variable is still looking at the old reference.  If you don't assign a new array but just alter its contents you will get what you expect.

For further explanation search for primitive types and reference types, such as https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch04_04.htm

Comment: thanks for your replay.In fact I want to change array data which is reference types.I change my question

Comment: not really a good idea to change your code, but you are suffering essentially from the same problem, in the first, you were copying the value, second you are making a copy of the reference, but then changing what the data references.  Your variable will still reference the original